# Prevent yarn from creating node_modules in monorepo root

Tags: yarnpkg

I'm using yarn with monorepos that contain several packages. For examples packages `foo` and `bar` might be located in `repo/foo` and `repo/bar` within the monorepo root `repo`. The problem is that I sometimes accidentally run `yarn` without parameters in the repository root instead of the packages directories. This creates a `repo/node_modules` directory and a `repo/yarn.lock` file. Can I somehow prevent yarn from creating `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` in the repository root directory?